Why do an 'internal error' is returned for a cloud function call by HTTPScallable?
I am calling a cloud function using httpscallable, but it gives me an error:[firebase_functions/internal] internal
Code snippet as follows:
customerPortal() async {
    debugPrint('customer portal pressed');
    HttpsCallable callable = FirebaseFunctions.instance
        .httpsCallable('ext-firestore-stripe-payments-createPortalLink');
    try {
      HttpsCallableResult result =
          await callable.call({'returnUrl': 'https://cancel.com'});

      debugPrint(result.data);
    } on FirebaseFunctionsException catch (error) {
      debugPrint(error.toString());
    }
  }

Why do I get this error? Any fix?

Did you add a try/catch block in your Cloud Function code? If yes you'll be able to see the error details in the logs (via the Google Cloud console). Without the error details and the Cloud Function code we cannot help you

The cloud function was generated by Stripe extension for payment. Not sure how can I configure that.

I read somewhere it can be related to the database location. Anywhere other than US central, it may give this error and needs to be declared upfront while initialising the app for firebase. Mine is europewest3. How can I define it?

I updated the code as follows: FirebaseFunctions.instanceFor(region: 'europe-west3').httpsCallable('ext-firestore-stripe-payments-createPortalLink'), and that particular error is gone now.

Ok cool, you may add this as an answer
